# query subcollection when key and value are different subcollections - linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I can't to query a collection like this below, in order to get the maximun "value" of a given "key", but key and value are subcollection of a collection

I need to get the max value of the "Revision" key of this collection:

```
- document 
    - id
    - description
    - key
        - version
        - revision
        - otherkey
    - value
        - "1.0"
        - 1
        - "othervalue"
- document 
    - id
    - description
    - key
        - version
        - revision
        - otherkey
    - value
        - "1.0"
        - 2
        - "othervalue"
- document 
    - id
    - description
    - key
        - version
        - revision
        - otherkey
    - value
        - "1.0"
        - 3
        - "othervalue"
- document 
    - id
    - description
    - key
        - version
        - revision
        - otherkey
    - value
        - "2.0"
        - 1
        - "othervalue"
```

any hints?

Comment: can you share some code, like classes, document list initialization...?

Answer (score 0):

Using the linq Zip function allows you to combine these two sub arrays into one. The following is an example of getting the maximum revision for each version:

```
void Main()
{
    var data = GetData();

    var maxRevisions = data
        .Select(x => new { Document = x, KeyValue = x.Key.Zip(x.Value, (k, v) => new { Key = k, Value = v }) })
        .GroupBy(x => new { Version = x.KeyValue.First(kv => kv.Key == "version").Value })
        .Select(x => new { Version = x.Key.Version, MaxRevision = x.Max(y => y.KeyValue.First(kv => kv.Key == "revision").Value) })
        .ToList();


    maxRevisions.ForEach(mr => Console.WriteLine($"Version: {mr.Version} - MaxRevision: {mr.MaxRevision}"));
}

public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<String> Key { get; set; }
    public List<String> Value { get; set; }
}

public static List<Document> GetData()
{
    return new List<Document> {
        new Document {
            Id = 1,
            Description = "one-one",
            Key = new List<string> { "version", "revision", "otherkey" },
            Value = new List<string> { "1.0", "1", "othervalue" }
        },
        new Document {
            Id = 1,
            Description = "one-two",
            Key = new List<string> { "version", "revision", "otherkey" },
            Value = new List<string> { "1.0", "2", "othervalue" }
        },
        new Document {
            Id = 1,
            Description = "one-three",
            Key = new List<string> { "version", "revision", "otherkey" },
            Value = new List<string> { "1.0", "3", "othervalue" }
        },
        new Document {
            Id = 1,
            Description = "two-one",
            Key = new List<string> { "version", "revision", "otherkey" },
            Value = new List<string> { "2.0", "1", "othervalue" }
        }};
}
```

This will output the following:

```
Version: 1.0 - MaxRevision: 3
Version: 2.0 - MaxRevision: 1
```

Comment: If this answer meets the requirements of a solution, then please mark it as such. If not, then please let me know how I can help, I'll be happy to expand on the above to get you the solution you're looking for.